# ReSharper Keep existing line breaks not working

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Under Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping | Preserve Existing Formatting I have "Keep existing line breaks" option checked. However, when I apply ReSharper Reformat Code function to file it removes my existing line breaks and places all the code in a statement on a single line.

Which setting could be annulling the "Keep existing line breaks" option and forcing the code on a single line?

I do have "Wrap long lines" under Line Wrapping unchecked but I don't think that should impact the "Keep existing line breaks" option.

```
Message = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(someString) ? 
    Properties.Resources.SomeResource : someBool ? 
        Message = Properties.Resources.SomeResource + Environment.NewLine + customMessage : customMessage;
```

After applying Reformat Code ReSharper function this statement with two line breaks becomes a single 240 character long line.

- Visual Studio 2015
- ReSharper 2017.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with the JetBrains CodeCleanup tool, take a look at the ternary operator formatting rules, for me it was the [wrap_ternary_expr_style](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/EditorConfig_CSHARP_LineBreaksPageSchema.html#resharper_csharp_wrap_ternary_expr_style) setting. I believe it's trying to fix the formatting of the ternary operator and since you don't have a max line length it condenses it down.